# Determine the number of graph vertices given some of their degrees

Tags: graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

Hello everyone interested. This is a question that seems simple but has me troubled.
I have a tree $G$ with an unknown number of vertices $\{v_j\}$. I know that there exists a vertex with degree $\deg(v_1)= 5$, two vertices with degrees $\deg(v_2),\deg(v_3)=4$, three vertices with degrees $\deg(v_4),\deg(v_5),\deg(v_6)=2$ and the rest of the vertices are leaves. 
How do I find the number of vertices?

By trying to plot the graph, I get the number $n$ of vertices must be over $6$, but I am confused on what the exact number is, or how the leaves come into the equation.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that you talk about leaves suggests that the graph is a tree. Is that true?

Comment: Yes! Will add that to the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
If you sum the degrees in a graph you get what is called the Handshake lemma:
$$\sum _{v_i}deg(v_i)=2E,$$
In a tree, as it contains no cycles(Hence just has $1$ face), Euler characteristic formula says that $V-E+F=2.$
Can you conclude?

Comment: So V-E=1. Also 2E=5+2*4+3*2+?. I'm stuck on what the degree for leaves is...

Comment: Yes, leaves mean that.

Comment: So V-E=1 and there are V-6 leaves. I get it! Thanks.